# Asp.net RadiobuttonList onselectedindexchanged do confirm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

code below!

```
<asp:RadioButtonListID='rblPosNegList' runat="server" 
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="White" 
onselectedindexchanged="rblPosNegList_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="POS" Selected="True">Positive List</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="NEG">Negative List</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onSuccess(e)
{
__doPostBack('rControl$PNRuleControl$rblPosNegList$1',");
}
function on Failure(e)
{

}
$(document).ready(function(){
var PosAndNegRadioButton=document.getElementsByName("rControl$PNRuleControl$rbl 
PosNegList");
$(PosAndNegRadioButton).change(function(e){
confirm("The Current selection is Positve/Negative..Please confirm 
!","Positive And Negative",",onSuccess,onFailure);
});
}); 
</script>
```

Cases :
1.whenever Positive List RadioButton selected it should confirm with ok / cancel.. if ok it goes to the next step!2. whenever Negative List RadioButton selected it should confirm with ok / cancel.. if ok it goes to the next step!

Answer (score 1):

First the disclaimers as you seem to be new:

- How you programm in ASP.Net is dependant on the [Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).
- The primary designtool is a programm flow chart.
- The most common design pattern MVC.
- Also no mater how much a page might *look* like a GUI, it is still a 1980 HTML Web Formular.

It sounds like this kind of check should happen on the Browser Side. That basically means some JavaScript. Commonly AJAX. ASP.Net afaik has some helper classes to support browser side code. This is about all I can tell you with the data you gave.

Comment: Above is the Javascript i have tried..i have made autopostback as false..the issue is that ,whenever the radio button is selected alternatively for the second time its not prompting !